# How to add icons to items in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation, icons, drawer

Now, the problem is, that the ArrayAdapter says, that I can't use the drawer_menu.xml because it requires the resource ID to be a TextView. If so, how do I add an icon, if I am only allowed to have a TextView in there?

drawer_menu.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] mDrawerQuantities = {"Angle", "Area", "Fuel", "Length", "Pressure",
        "Speed", "Temperature", "Time", "Volume", "Weight"};
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_menu, mDrawerQuantities));

}
```

content_main.xml:

```
     <!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069797/add-icons-to-android-navigation-drawer

Comment: Please check this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html. The new design support library makes it simpler

Answer (score 0):

To use your custom layout for listview you have to create your own adapter, For this you have to extend `BaseAdapter`, Here is an example

[Find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192815/how-to-add-customised-layout-to-arrayadapter/28192966#28192966)

Then create an instance of your custom adapter and then set it to listview instead of `ArrayAdapter`.